# foreach loop with more than one step

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am using `PDO` to get result from database and then using `foreach` loop to display data.

my code is

```
$result1=$objPage->getGallery($id);
foreach($result1 as $row)
{

    echo "pic1=" . $row['pic']; 
    echo "pic2=" . $row['pic']; 
    echo "pic3=" . $row['pic']; 
    echo "<br>";    
}
```

Actually, I want to display three pictures names in one line and then next 3 names.

But now its printing one name 3 times.

Comment: BTW, PDO has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an external flag, like this:

```
$flag = 0;
$result1=$objPage->getGallery($id);
foreach($result1 as $row) {
    echo "pic" . ($flag + 1) . "=" . $row['pic'];
    if( $flag % 3 == 0 )
        echo "<br>";
    $flag++;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
$result1=$objPage->getGallery($id);
$count = 0;
foreach($result1 as $row)
{
    echo "pic" . $count + 1 . "=" . $row['pic']; 
    if( $count % 3 == 2 )
    {
        echo "<br>";    
    }
    $count++;
}
```

**Information**

1. [Modulo %](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Answer (score 2):

first, prepare your data

```
$data = $objPage->getGallery($id);
$data = array_chunk($data,3);
```

then output it

```
<table>
<? foreach($data as $chunk): ?>
  <tr>
<? foreach($chunk as $row): ?>
    <td><img src="<?=$row['pic']?>"></td>
<? endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use modulo as suggested by others, but how about this more compact method?

```
$result1 = $objPage->getGallery($id);
$separators = array('', '', '<br/>');
foreach ($result1 as $index => $row) {
    echo 'pic' . ($index % 3) . '=' . $row['pic'] . $separators[$index % 3];
}
```